# What's the name of this vertical carousel UI element?

Tags: landing-page, onboarding, carousel

[image]
This 'vertical carousel' pattern seems really powerful for 'how it works' sections since, unlike a horizontal carousel, you can easily read through the steps without interacting with it. We're creating a marketing homepage using bootstrap + the Pillar library but

what's it called?

Answer (score 3):

These look like stylized **vertical tabs**.

(I've taken a look at what appears to be the source page of your image --https://www.fullstory.com/features/ )

**Examples of vertical tabs**

**CSS & JavaScript** (w3 Schools) -- https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_vertical_tabs.asp

**CSS Only** (CodePen) -- https://codepen.io/nik-savchenko/pen/xDIAe

**Bootstrap Specific** (CodePen) -- https://codepen.io/akhilmekkatt/pen/YGqadp

Comment: Awesome. Great examples and enough to get me started. Hazaa!

Answer (score 1):

## Slider Synching

http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

You just have to customize the kenwheeler as per your requirement and it should work just right.